# Google Chrome console shows an error

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I am getting this error in Google Chrome, when I open new tab, it shows `chrome://thumb/https://github.com/` in console.

[image: Chrome Console]

Comment: Is `github` one of the URLs you have bookmarked in your new tab page? Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7, I haven't bookmarked github anywhere in any browser. I don't even use it, just visited once.

Comment: Do you have a github thumbnail in your most visited sites page ?Are you getting this error on everypage ?

Comment: This error is on every new tab I open, and yes, I am having github in most visited page.